# How to know (pragmatically) correct maven artifact-id group-id for a jar name

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Could you please let me know if there is any search service available where I can search maven artifact-id, group-id for a jar pragmatically.

The idea is to build a simple tool (may be a jar running from console) which scans my lib directory (for all jar names) and produces a pom file for them.

As of now when I need to generate the pom xml, I do it manually by searching for artifact-id, group-id on 
mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1.

I am just thinking of any service which takes jar name (ex. commons-collections 3.2.1) in request and returns the response like below:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
     <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Any pointers to existing tools would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could choose [maven central search capabilities](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccommons-collections) which would result in a list of artifacts. Furthermore the Nexus for Maven Central has [REST API](http://search.maven.org/#api) which can be used for such purposes.

Apart from the above such a tool which you have in mind wouldn't work cause it must bear in mind that there are transitive dependencies which is simply to solve not to take into the pom file as a dependency.